# AVPlayer iOS swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, avplayer

I am facing a problem with my App I have a video inside a `NavigationView` (3rd level view) when user put the video in full screen and drag up the video the screen becomes black and the video continues playing on background.

**SwiftUI and Swift 5**

Also i am looking for any method with SwiftUI to get into full screen video once the user Tap the button instead loading inside a new view.

**Edit**

I figured out the drag up problem, if some one is facing the same issue check if you disabled any orientations mode in your app in my case it fixed the issue app must be enabled in all orientations mode.

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? I have same problem, everything works fine until i put it in NavigationView